# In python how to scrape the data behind the chart?

Tags: javascript, selenium, web-scraping

I want to use python to scrape the data behind the historical price chart from this url: https://www.gurufocus.com/stock/HKSE:00700/summary
[image]

I found an API end-point containing all the data I wanted,
[image]

But unfortunately, it is encrypted with some parameters in the request headers that's hard to break:
[image]

I don't know if there is still any to get the data without using Selenium. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There's a better way than hovering over every data point, you can look at the Response tab of the Network section in the Chrome developer tools. All the data will be there for copying and pasting - attaching a snippet below:

```json
{"HK00HF":[["2019-01-02",306.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-01-03",305],["2019-01-04",310.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-01-07",317.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-01-08",315.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-01-09",327.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-01-10",329],["2019-01-11",331.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2019-01-14",321.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-01-15",330],["2019-01-16",331],["2019-01-17",331.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2019-01-18",337],["2019-01-21",340],["2019-01-22",335.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-01-23",333.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2019-01-24",330.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2019-01-25",343.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-01-28",341.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-01-29",342.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2019-01-30",344.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2019-01-31",346],["2019-02-01",348],["2019-02-04",347.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-02-08",345.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-02-11",352],["2019-02-12",351.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2019-02-13",347.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-02-14",341.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-02-15",333.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-02-18",339.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-02-19",336.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-02-20",341],["2019-02-21",343.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2019-02-22",344],["2019-02-25",343.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-02-26",343],["2019-02-27",340.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2019-02-28",335.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-03-01",336.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2019-03-04",346.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-03-05",361.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2019-03-06",362],["2019-03-07",355.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2019-03-08",347],["2019-03-11",354.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-03-12",361],["2019-03-13",358.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2019-03-14",357.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-03-15",359],["2019-03-18",368.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-03-19",370],["2019-03-20",370],["2019-03-21",363],["2019-03-22",365],["2019-03-25",353.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-03-26",351.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2019-03-27",354.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-03-28",354],["2019-03-29",361],["2019-04-01",365],["2019-04-02",366],["2019-04-03",378],["2019-04-04",376],["2019-04-08",380.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2019-04-09",383.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-04-10",388.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-04-11",391.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2019-04-12",393.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-04-15",388.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2019-04-16",393.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-04-17",395.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-04-18",391.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-04-23",393],["2019-04-24",393],["2019-04-25",382.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-04-26",384],["2019-04-29",390.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-04-30",388],["2019-05-02",391.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2019-05-03",387.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-05-06",375.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-05-07",380.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-05-08",384.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-05-09",375.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-05-10",382],["2019-05-14",370.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-05-15",374],["2019-05-16",365.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-05-17",355.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-05-20",342],["2019-05-21",341.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2019-05-22",339],["2019-05-23",326],["2019-05-24",324.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-05-27",323.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-05-28",325.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-05-29",322],["2019-05-30",324.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2019-05-31",326],["2019-06-03",333.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-06-04",327.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2019-06-05",331],["2019-06-06",330.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2019-06-10",343],["2019-06-11",344.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-06-12",337.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2019-06-13",334.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2019-06-14",330],["2019-06-17",329],["2019-06-18",334],["2019-06-19",347.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2019-06-20",354],["2019-06-21",354.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2019-06-24",355.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-06-25",349.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2019-06-26",349],["2019-06-27",352.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-06-28",352.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-07-02",362.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2019-07-03",360.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2019-07-04",360],["2019-07-05",359.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-07-08",351],["2019-07-09",350.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-07-10",356.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-07-11",357.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2019-07-12",355],["2019-07-15",360.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-07-16",362.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-07-17",363.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2019-07-18",356.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-07-19",361.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-07-22",357.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-07-23",358.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-07-24",365.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-07-25",372.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2019-07-26",370.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2019-07-29",372.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2019-07-30",373.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2019-07-31",368.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2019-08-01",370],["2019-08-02",355.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-08-05",340.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-08-06",337.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2019-08-07",338.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-08-08",342.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2019-08-09",338.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2019-08-12",340],["2019-08-13",334],["2019-08-14",340],["2019-08-15",330.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2019-08-16",326.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2019-08-19",336.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-08-20",333.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2019-08-21",332.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-08-22",331],["2019-08-23",334.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2019-08-26",326],["2019-08-27",326.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2019-08-28",319],["2019-08-29",320.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2019-08-30",324.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-09-02",331.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2019-09-03",329.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2019-09-04",341.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2019-09-05",341.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2019-09-06",343.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2019-09-09",342.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2019-09-10",340.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2019-09-11",346],["2019-09-12",349.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2019-09-13",349.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-09-16",346.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-09-17",343.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-09-18",343],["2019-09-19",338.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2019-09-20",337.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-09-23",335.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-09-24",335.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-09-25",328.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2019-09-26",332.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2019-09-27",329.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2019-09-30",330.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2019-10-02",325],["2019-10-03",325.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2019-10-04",322.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-10-08",323.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-10-09",318.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2019-10-10",318.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-10-11",324.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-10-14",328.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2019-10-15",328.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-10-16",331],["2019-10-17",331],["2019-10-18",331],["2019-10-21",324.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-10-22",327.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-10-23",320],["2019-10-24",319],["2019-10-25",316.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-10-28",322],["2019-10-29",317],["2019-10-30",316.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2019-10-31",320.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-11-01",321.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-11-04",327.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-11-05",333],["2019-11-06",334],["2019-11-07",333.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-11-08",327.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2019-11-11",323],["2019-11-12",330.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2019-11-13",327.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2019-11-14",319.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-11-15",320],["2019-11-18",330],["2019-11-19",336.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-11-20",335.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-11-21",329.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2019-11-22",333.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-11-25",338.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-11-26",335.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-11-27",335],["2019-11-28",338],["2019-11-29",331.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-12-02",333],["2019-12-03",331],["2019-12-04",328.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-12-05",330],["2019-12-06",335.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-12-09",336.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2019-12-10",336.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-12-11",340],["2019-12-12",349],["2019-12-13",361],["2019-12-16",359.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-12-17",371.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2019-12-18",377.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-12-19",375.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2019-12-20",375.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2019-12-23",377.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-12-24",376.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2019-12-27",384],["2019-12-30",383.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2019-12-31",375.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2020-01-02",382.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2020-01-03",383],["2020-01-06",377.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2020-01-07",385.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2020-01-08",382],["2020-01-09",390],["2020-01-10",398.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2020-01-13",406.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2020-01-14",400.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2020-01-15",398.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2020-01-16",400],["2020-01-17",399],["2020-01-20",396],["2020-01-21",385.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2020-01-22",391],["2020-01-23",385.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2020-01-24",385.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2020-01-29",383.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2020-01-30",375],["2020-01-31",373],["2020-02-03",380],["2020-02-04",393],["2020-02-05",392.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2020-02-06",400],["2020-02-07",402.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2020-02-10",400.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2020-02-11",409],["2020-02-12",411],["2020-02-13",416.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2020-02-14",415],["2020-02-17",416.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2020-02-18",408.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2020-02-19",411.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2020-02-20",410],["2020-02-21",401],["2020-02-24",390.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2020-02-25",401.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2020-02-26",399.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2020-02-27",399.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2020-02-28",386],["2020-03-02",389.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2020-03-03",394],["2020-03-04",394],["2020-03-05",406.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2020-03-06",395.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2020-03-09",377.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2020-03-10",383],["2020-03-11",378.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2020-03-12",363.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2020-03-13",365],["2020-03-16",341.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2020-03-17",349.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2020-03-18",334],["2020-03-19",343],["2020-03-20",359.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2020-03-23",348],["2020-03-24",365.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2020-03-25",380],["2020-03-26",381.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2020-03-27",382.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2020-03-30",376.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2020-03-31",380.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2020-04-01",374.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2020-04-02",379.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2020-04-03",376.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2020-04-06",381.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2020-04-07",387.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2020-04-08",385],["2020-04-09",391.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2020-04-14",395],["2020-04-15",395],["2020-04-16",406.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2020-04-17",409.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2020-04-20",408.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2020-04-21",400.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2020-04-22",409.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2020-04-23",411.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2020-04-24",406.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2020-04-27",413],["2020-04-28",417.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2020-04-29",417],["2020-05-04",400],["2020-05-05",406],["2020-05-06",410],["2020-05-07",407.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2020-05-08",418.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2020-05-11",435],["2020-05-12",431],["2020-05-13",429.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2020-05-14",430.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2020-05-15",421.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2020-05-18",423],["2020-05-19",430],["2020-05-20",440],["2020-05-21",433.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2020-05-22",412.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2020-05-25",416.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2020-05-26",425.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2020-05-27",420],["2020-05-28",408.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2020-05-29",410.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2020-06-01",429],["2020-06-02",430.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2020-06-03",432.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2020-06-04",435],["2020-06-05",434.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2020-06-08",430],["2020-06-09",433.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2020-06-10",446.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2020-06-11",442.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2020-06-12",441],["2020-06-15",433.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2020-06-16",448.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2020-06-17",450.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2020-06-18",458],["2020-06-19",460.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2020-06-22",474.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2020-06-23",497.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2020-06-24",490.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2020-06-26",485],["2020-06-29",486],["2020-06-30",498.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2020-07-02",518.5],["2020-07-03",524.5],["2020-07-06",520],["2020-07-07",516],["2020-07-08",543],["2020-07-09",563],["2020-07-10",546.5],["2020-07-13",541],["2020-07-14",525],["2020-07-15",543],["2020-07-16",513],["2020-07-17",521],["2020-07-20",522.5],["2020-07-21",564],["2020-07-22",539],["2020-07-23",557],["2020-07-24",528],["2020-07-27",520],["2020-07-28",543.5],["2020-07-29",541.5],["2020-07-30",535],["2020-07-31",534],["2020-08-03",539],["2020-08-04",550],["2020-08-05",561],["2020-08-06",555.5],["2020-08-07",527.5],["2020-08-10",502],["2020-08-11",513.5],["2020-08-12",520.5],["2020-08-13",510],["2020-08-14",506.5],["2020-08-17",504.5],["2020-08-18",512],["2020-08-19",506],["2020-08-20",508],["2020-08-21",518],["2020-08-24",548],["2020-08-25",544.5],["2020-08-26",551.5],["2020-08-27",558],["2020-08-28",540.5],["2020-08-31",530.5],["2020-09-01",539],["2020-09-02",545],["2020-09-03",534],["2020-09-04",518],["2020-09-07",511],["2020-09-08",508.5],["2020-09-09",504],["2020-09-10",506],["2020-09-11",516],["2020-09-14",529.5],["2020-09-15",529.5],["2020-09-16",534.5],["2020-09-17",527],["2020-09-18",525],["2020-09-21",516.5],["2020-09-22",511.5],["2020-09-23",514],["2020-09-24",505],["2020-09-25",503.5],["2020-09-28",506],["2020-09-29",505.5],["2020-09-30",511.5],["2020-10-05",525],["2020-10-06",527.5],["2020-10-07",535],["2020-10-08",535],["2020-10-09",539.5],["2020-10-12",557],["2020-10-14",573.5],["2020-10-15",552],["2020-10-16",557],["2020-10-19",561.5],["2020-10-20",564.5],["2020-10-21",566.5],["2020-10-22",563.5],["2020-10-23",561.5],["2020-10-27",585],["2020-10-28",601],["2020-10-29",605],["2020-10-30",591],["2020-11-02",601.5],["2020-11-03",598],["2020-11-04",588.5],["2020-11-05",625],["2020-11-06",614.5],["2020-11-09",622.5],["2020-11-10",595],["2020-11-11",551],["2020-11-12",577],["2020-11-13",602],["2020-11-16",597],["2020-11-17",581.5],["2020-11-18",589],["2020-11-19",573],["2020-11-20",588],["2020-11-23",586],["2020-11-24",584],["2020-11-25",573],["2020-11-26",586],["2020-11-27",583],["2020-11-30",563],["2020-12-01",578],["2020-12-02",574],["2020-12-03",589],["2020-12-04",588.5],["2020-12-07",583.5],["2020-12-08",583],["2020-12-09",585],["2020-12-10",578],["2020-12-11",588],["2020-12-14",571],["2020-12-15",560],["2020-12-16",571.5],["2020-12-17",583],["2020-12-18",580],["2020-12-21",572],["2020-12-22",572.5],["2020-12-23",571],["2020-12-24",557.5],["2020-12-28",519],["2020-12-29",530.5],["2020-12-30",559.5],["2020-12-31",566],["2021-01-04",572.5],["2021-01-05",583.5],["2021-01-06",596.5],["2021-01-07",568.5],["2021-01-08",573],["2021-01-11",591],["2021-01-12",590],["2021-01-13",596],["2021-01-14",629.5],["2021-01-15",645],["2021-01-18",657],["2021-01-19",655],["2021-01-20",679.5],["2021-01-21",682.5],["2021-01-22",691],["2021-01-25",766.5],["2021-01-26",718.5],["2021-01-27",701.5],["2021-01-28",681],["2021-01-29",681.5],["2021-02-01",712],["2021-02-02",724.5],["2021-02-03",736],["2021-02-04",735.5],["2021-02-05",733],["2021-02-08",736.5],["2021-02-09",740.5],["2021-02-10",761],["2021-02-11",757],["2021-02-16",745],["2021-02-17",757.5],["2021-02-18",747.5],["2021-02-19",741],["2021-02-22",713.5],["2021-02-23",707],["2021-02-24",687],["2021-02-25",691.5],["2021-02-26",662.5],["2021-03-01",697],["2021-03-02",698],["2021-03-03",723],["2021-03-04",690],["2021-03-05",679],["2021-03-08",642.5],["2021-03-09",644],["2021-03-10",658.5],["2021-03-11",680.5],["2021-03-12",650.5],["2021-03-15",628],["2021-03-16",630.5],["2021-03-17",624.5],["2021-03-18",640.5],["2021-03-19",628],["2021-03-22",633.5],["2021-03-23",628.5],["2021-03-24",623.5],["2021-03-25",606],["2021-03-26",620],["2021-03-29",612],["2021-03-30",609.5],["2021-03-31",610],["2021-04-01",654],["2021-04-07",629.5],["2021-04-08",620],["2021-04-09",620.5],["2021-04-12",613.5],["2021-04-13",608],["2021-04-14",623.5],["2021-04-15",620],["2021-04-16",632],["2021-04-19",627],["2021-04-20",622.5],["2021-04-21",609],["2021-04-22",621],["2021-04-23",632],["2021-04-26",628.5],["2021-04-27",625],["2021-04-28",628],["2021-04-29",631.5],["2021-04-30",623],["2021-05-03",624.5],["2021-05-04",622],["2021-05-05",610.5],["2021-05-06",610.5],["2021-05-07",600],["2021-05-10",595],["2021-05-11",584.5],["2021-05-12",598.5],["2021-05-13",580],["2021-05-14",583],["2021-05-17",600.5],["2021-05-18",607.5],["2021-05-20",609],["2021-05-21",588.5],["2021-05-24",585.5],["2021-05-25",610],["2021-05-26",618],["2021-05-27",605.5],["2021-05-28",601.5],["2021-05-31",619],["2021-06-01",628],["2021-06-02",628.5],["2021-06-03",615.5],["2021-06-04",611.5],["2021-06-07",600.5],["2021-06-08",601],["2021-06-09",603],["2021-06-10",600.5],["2021-06-11",596],["2021-06-15",600],["2021-06-16",596.5],["2021-06-17",599],["2021-06-18",603],["2021-06-21",590.5],["2021-06-22",573.5],["2021-06-23",582.5],["2021-06-24",583],["2021-06-25",598.5],["2021-06-28",595.5],["2021-06-29",590.5],["2021-06-30",584],["2021-07-02",574.5],["2021-07-05",554],["2021-07-06",559],["2021-07-07",548.5],["2021-07-08",528],["2021-07-09",538.5],["2021-07-12",534.5],["2021-07-13",555.5],["2021-07-14",556.5],["2021-07-15",565],["2021-07-16",564],["2021-07-19",549.5],["2021-07-20",542.5],["2021-07-21",538],["2021-07-22",544],["2021-07-23",531],["2021-07-26",490],["2021-07-27",446],["2021-07-28",447.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2021-07-29",492],["2021-07-30",479],["2021-08-02",475],["2021-08-03",446],["2021-08-04",456.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2021-08-05",439],["2021-08-06",453.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2021-08-09",461.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2021-08-10",486.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2021-08-11",484],["2021-08-12",482],["2021-08-13",470.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2021-08-16",453.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2021-08-17",435],["2021-08-18",436.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2021-08-19",421.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2021-08-20",425.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2021-08-23",433.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2021-08-24",472],["2021-08-25",474.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625],["2021-08-26",471.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2021-08-27",466.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2021-08-30",465.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2021-08-31",481.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2021-09-01",488.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2021-09-02",496],["2021-09-03",488],["2021-09-06",505],["2021-09-07",515.5],["2021-09-08",524.5],["2021-09-09",480],["2021-09-10",490],["2021-09-13",478],["2021-09-14",472.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2021-09-15",453.3999999999999772626324556767940521240234375],["2021-09-16",451],["2021-09-17",461.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125],["2021-09-20",454.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2021-09-21",450],["2021-09-23",463.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2021-09-24",460.19999999999998863131622783839702606201171875],["2021-09-27",464.6000000000000227373675443232059478759765625]]}
```